# Create StackExchange site to specifc jQuery-Use questions?

Tags: discussion, area-51, migration, jquery

I could notice an incredibly high amount of jQuery questions regarding very specific uses of Jquery, like: `I got this html and I want to do Foo, how?` or `This is my code, why it does not work?`.

Makes me wonder if Stackoverflow is the correct place for that. What do you think?

Comment: Does my question `does not show any research effort`, `is unclear` or `is not useful`?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: @arkilus On meta, that's exactly what downvotes mean - disagreement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such jQuery questions are low quality, show no effort and have been answered 1,000 times all across the internet. They should be downvoted, closed and deleted from <s>the internet</s> SO

There is **no** need to create a SE site just for this. <sup>Although if we did, it might improve the quality of jQuery tag</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Stack Overflow is the right place for those kinds of questions. Ideally with more detail. There's no need to split jQuery into its own site.

But for the sake of completeness, to propose a new site, you have to go to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com). Proposals for sites whose subject matter would be entirely on-topic on an existing site (e.g. jQuery on Stack Overflow) are likely to be closed, though.